# Wordpress URL rewrite subfolder to another subfolder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have been trying for several hours now to do a simple url rewrite on a fresh wordpress install and not having any luck.

Suppose my website has a page with some content
-example.com/samplepage

If someone types in the browser example.com/au/samplepage,

I want to rewrite the URL so it loads example.com/samplepage but keeping example.com/au/samplepage in the browser URL

I have tried ^ax/?(.*)$ /global/$1 [L] in my htaccess but no luck. I feel as though wordpress is over-writing something as it just displays the 404 error page.

I can however do a redirect from example.com/au/samplepage to example.com/samplepage where the browser URL example.com/samplepage, however if I want to keep the original URL, it seems impossible.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^au/?(.*)$ /$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

I wouldn't think this would need mod_proxy? I have also tried the [PT] flag but no luck.

Comment: In which directory your wordpress installed ?

Comment: Hello, it is in the root directory.

Comment: We want to be able to apply country based paths:

Comment: example.com/au/page1

Comment: example.com/au/page1, example.com/sg/page1 but pull the content from example.com/page. the country pages won't exist, it just mirrors the content on /page